# TypeError: can't send non-None value to a just-started coroutine discord.py

Tags: discord.py

this error comes up when I try to send a message to the owner with a bot.
the line of code that creates the error:

```
await owner.send([report_member, "was reported for rule", rule])
```

owner:

```py
owner = guild.fetch_member(not telling you the id)
```

Comment: `Guild.fetch_member` is a coroutine, you should await it

Comment: thank you this really helps

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, `Guild.fetch_member` is a coroutine, you should await it

```py
owner = await guild.fetch_member(ID)
await owner.send(...)
```

#### Reference:

- [`Guild.fetch_member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.fetch_member)