# Discord.py. Type error : Cannot send non-None type value to a just started coroutine

Tags: discord.py

Im trying to make a discord bot with a basic cross-channel communication thing like some other bots, but whilst trying that i keep getting this issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 441, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Desktop\Code Projects\DiscordBot.py", line 90, in MessageResponder
    await client.fetch_channel(Connections[message.channel.id]).send(message)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: can't send non-None value to a just-started coroutine
```

I've searched for possible answers towards this and did find an old post similar to this years ago but the only solution was awaiting it, so i did just that
however the same issue still keeps popping up and i have no idea why.
[TypeError: can't send non-None value to a just-started coroutine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55696072/typeerror-cant-send-non-none-value-to-a-just-started-coroutine)
[Discord.py(v 1.5.0) : TypeError: can't send non-None value to a just-started generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65312592/discord-pyv-1-5-0-typeerror-cant-send-non-none-value-to-a-just-started-gen)
[TypeError: can't send non-None value to a just-started coroutine discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66088791/typeerror-cant-send-non-none-value-to-a-just-started-coroutine-discord-py)

Code:

```
@client.listen("on_message")
async def MessageResponder(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    try:
        await client.fetch_channel(Connections[message.channel.id]).send(message)
        Idmain = list(Connections.keys())[list(Connections.values()).index(message.channel.id)]
        if Idmain and message.channel.id in Connections:
            try: 
                CheckActivity[f"{Idmain}/{message.channel.id}"] += 1
            except KeyError:
                CheckActivity[f"{message.channel.id}/{Idmain}"] += 1
    except KeyError:
        return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on line 90, you are using a coroutine to get a channel object, and it needs to be awaited. the `.send()` method is also a coroutine, and there is no way to handle them both in one line (is there a way?)

try seperating the two coroutines:

```
@client.listen("on_message")
async def MessageResponder(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    try:
        channel = await client.fetch_channel(Connections[message.channel.id])
        await channel.send(message)
        Idmain = list(Connections.keys())[list(Connections.values()).index(message.channel.id)]
        if Idmain and message.channel.id in Connections:
            try: 
                CheckActivity[f"{Idmain}/{message.channel.id}"] += 1
            except KeyError:
                CheckActivity[f"{message.channel.id}/{Idmain}"] += 1
    except KeyError:
        return
```

i assume this would work too:

```
@client.listen("on_message")
async def MessageResponder(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    try:
        await message.channel.send(message)
        Idmain = list(Connections.keys())[list(Connections.values()).index(message.channel.id)]
        if Idmain and message.channel.id in Connections:
            try: 
                CheckActivity[f"{Idmain}/{message.channel.id}"] += 1
            except KeyError:
                CheckActivity[f"{message.channel.id}/{Idmain}"] += 1
    except KeyError:
        return
```